# IOS url Scheme launch custom UIView inside my application

Tags: ios, url-scheme

I have a custom UIView in my application that I would like to make available to other applications to call  using a url scheme. How would I accomplish this?

I’m able to call the application with a url scheme and it launches the application with the custom UIView, but it does not leave the calling application in place.

I would like to just create the custom UIView and have it display over a certain part of the screen in the calling application. Can this be done? I would also like to call this from a UIWebView with JavaScript window.location.

Thank You

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/37677349/2522603 i m facing this issue, as u have tried. is it possible or not. please do let me know

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't display custom UIView over part of the screen on top of calling app. All you can do it add a url handler so your app comes to foreground when calling app initiates your custom url.

I'm not sure about your second question, but I would guess it won't work - why don't you try opening your custom url in a UIWebView?

Comment: thank you and you are correct about the UIView. I will try to work with a direct transfer to my app.  I have tried the UIWebView with JavaScript calling the url scheme of my app, but on exit it returns to the home screen.  I don’t think even a passed url scheme will return to the same position in the calling app.  Is there any other way?

Comment: Let me understand this - you open your custom URL in app A and it opens app B which is registered to handle the url. Now you want to return to A when you are done in B. Correct? Unless you have control over app A, there is no way to do this. If you own A - you can create custom url for A and open that url when you're done in B. This will launch A. Hope that clarifies things.

Comment: Thanks again. I could limit the use of app A to those with a custom url, but it is of no use if it would just return the caller (app A). I don't think it will return to the same place in the calling (app A).